# How to initialize google test without main?

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries, googletest

I have code like this in exe

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){ 
if(argc>1)
{
//do something
}
else
{
StartGoogleTest(argc ,argv);
}
}
```

`StartGoogleTest` is in shared library. I have to pass command line arguments to start or to initialize google test framework. 
Following is `StartGoodleTest.cpp`:

```
TEST(SomeClass, myTest)
{
  //some code 
}
StartGoodleTest(int &argc, char** &argv)
{
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);

  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

This code crashes at `InitGoogleTest`. Is there any way to initialize google test without command line arguments or any other way to initialize google test without main?

Comment: The problem (crash) is apparently in code not shown.

Comment: ok but is there any way to start google test without main and without sending command line arguments

Comment: Is the problem that you are calling StartGoogleTest and have function called StartGoodleTest?

Comment: can you provide a stack trace?

Comment: @LawfulEvil problem is in StartGoogleTest
problem is at   testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);

Comment: How would you initialize it without main? You need a main function if you are creating an executable. What are you trying to accomplish here? Please be more specific!

Comment: @MarkoPopovic I don't want to start unit tests from main i want to start from shared library that is aim

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the goal or what the two pieces of code have to do with each other.   I can't take your code and try it out for myself, so I am left to guess which typos are typos and which are bugs in the original code.   Goodle?   &argc?   TEST or RUN_ALL_TEST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `StartGoogleTest` function is the problem, change it like this:

```
int StartGoogleTest(int argc, char** argv)
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);

    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

As far as the initialization without main goes, the answer is no. You can put the function `StartGoogleTest` inside a shared library, but at some point you will have to create an executable with a main function which will have to link with that library and call `StartGoogleTest` (either in main or in some sub-routine) to initialize googletest and run test cases.

Comment: we can initiate test  without command line arguments we can just keep argc and argv local and initialize argv and argc locally it works fine

Comment: @ganesh Yes, you can eliminate passing of real command line args that main receives and use local instead. However, I would not suggest that you do that because you lose a lot of flexibility (for example, you cannot specify a filter for tests).